# How do I customize <title> of SilverStripe pages

Tags: silverstripe

How do I customize the `<title>` of SilverStripe pages?

Right now it's

```
<title><% if $MetaTitle %>$MetaTitle<% else %>$Title<% end_if %> &raquo; $SiteConfig.Title</title>
```

Comment: Are changes to the above not taking effect? Does your template include $MetaTags(true) or $MetaTags(false)? It should be the latter if you're including your own title tag. Beyond that we'll need more detail about what you're wanting to accomplish.

Comment: I think I should set $MetaTags(false), it's true right now   But I don't know the next step to have the title beside what I have right now which is "Menu Name>>Site Name" (the output of the code I originally submitted). I want to customize the <title> for each page.

Comment: Once you change that true to false, I you follow 3dgoo's answer below. You can of course remove the " &raquo; $SiteConfig.Title" if you want to be able to just use MetaTitle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current page template page `<title>` tag is:

```
<title>
    <% if $MetaTitle %>$MetaTitle<% else %>$Title<% end_if %> 
    &raquo; $SiteConfig.Title
</title>
```

You can change this to use any variable or content that you would like.

Your current template code checks if the page has a `$MetaTitle` defined. If it does it will use this. Otherwise it will use the page `$Title`.

The last part adds the site title `$SiteConfig.Title` to the end. This field can be found in the CMS on the Settings tab.

The `MetaTitle` variable was removed from the core SilverStripe code in 3.1. If you would like to add this functionality back in you can do this by installing the [SilverStripe MetaTitle module](https://github.com/kinglozzer/silverstripe-metatitle/) or by adding the variable and input to your Page class yourself.

Here is some code to add the `MetaTitle` variable to the `Page` class:

```php
class Page extends SiteTree {

    private static $db = array(
        'MetaTitle' => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab(
            'Root.Main',
            TextField::create('MetaTitle')
                ->setRightTitle('Shown at the top of the browser window and used as the "linked text" by search engines.')
                ->addExtraClass('help'),
            'MetaDescription'
        );

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

The variable will appear in the CMS on each page underneath the `Content` field.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the page title in the CMS in the "Title" field.

If you wish to change the title of the entire site, edit the Title in the Site Configuration section (which matches up to `$SiteConfig.Title`).

In general, those variables are just populated from the CMS, so feel free to customize them with other variables, or edit their values in the CMS as you need.

Comment: What I wanted to customize for each page is the <title></title> which appears when you point at the tab of the browser.